# Using paypal express checkout in Android

Tags: android, token, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I want to use paypal express checkout in paypal to get the token ID to send the ID to the server. At the moment I am using the general paypal and I get a response like this:

```
{
    "payment": {
        "short_description": "Coffee Payment",
        "amount": "24",
        "currency_code": "AUD"
    },
    "client": {
        "platform": "Android",
        "paypal_sdk_version": "1.2.3",
        "product_name": "PayPal Android SDK; ",
        "environment": "sandbox"
    },
    "proof_of_payment": {
        "adaptive_payment": {
            "timestamp": "2014-03-26T03:22:09+0000",
            "payment_exec_status": "COMPLETED",
            "app_id": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
            "pay_key": "AP-6N7046464K788532B"
        }
    }
}
```

But I need to get the token using paypal express. I would greatly appreciate if the way to do this can be shown.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but the "papal express" in your question title gave me a laugh.

Comment: could you explain the reason?

Comment: It's a typo. Instead of "PayPal", you typed "papal", which is a reference to the Pope.

Answer (score 0):

That sample is using Adaptive Payments.  The [Express Checkout portion of the REST CreatePayment API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/) is what you're after.

Comment: My problem is implementing express checkout. Any tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

i have done implementation. If you have read the docs in the paypal developer page, the only problem you should be having is generating the access token. The access token is generated as follows:

```
<?php 

require_once ("include/braintree_init.php");
require_once 'vendor/braintree/braintree_php/lib/Braintree.php';

/*if(file_exists(__DIR__ . "/../.env")) {
    $dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__ . "/../");
    $dotenv->load();
}*/
    $clientToken = $gateway->clientToken()->generate();

    $output = json_encode(array("response" =>$clientToken)) ;
    echo $output;
```

After send the output to your android. And that's it. But you will have to have the include files that i have included.